# Sum of the union of probabilities proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am unsure how to prove that $P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k)$. The left hand side looks like the the general inclusion-exclusion formula, but the right side does not. However, it seems like a proof by induction would work well for this problem, but I'm not sure how to make the jump after the base case of $n=2$.

Comment: assuming you are working with a finite sample space, you can prove it by showing that each outcome in the union is counted at least once in the sum.

Comment: You don't have a union of probabilities; you have a union of events.  And you don't have a sum of a union; you have a sum of probabilities. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

If you've already proved the base case $P(A_1\cup A_2) \le P(A_1)+P(A_2)$, then you can do this:
\begin{align}
& P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n \cup A_{n+1}) \\[10pt]
= {} & P( \Big( A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n \Big) \cup A_{n+1}) \\[10pt]
\le {} & P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) + P(A_{n+1}) & & \text{by the base case applied to these two events,} \\[10pt]
\le {} & \Big( P(A_1) + \cdots + P(A_n) \Big) + P(A_{n+1}) & & \text{by the induction hypothesis.} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Outline: Let $B_1=A_1$. For each $i\gt 1$, let $B_i=A_i\setminus(A_1\cup \dots \cup A_{i-1})$. Then (i) the union of the $B_i$ is the same as the union of the $A_i$, and (ii) the $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint and (iii) each $B_i$ is a subset of the corresponding $A_i$.